# Need to show profile on event for someone logged in

Tags: civievent

I am trying to set up an event registration form. The guests are asked to bring a food item to share, and the committee wants to know who is bringing what, so they want the user to enter a description of what they are bringing.  From what I have read, I set up a profile with an added field. The problem I have is that when a person has logged in to Wordpress, the profile does not show up rather the page shows their name and asks if that is for whom they are registering.  Is there a way for the added fields in a profile to always be displayed? Is there a better way for me to try to do this?

Comment: You added the profile to the event registration? Also, check you are not logged in as admin when you test this. You should log in as the user.

Answer (score 1):

If your profile includes some custom fields, check your permissions to ensure that those logged-in users have permissions to access the custom fields.  (And if users don't have to log in to register, make sure anonymous users have that access too.)